# Out-File or Add-Content result in empty file

Tags: powershell-2.0, file-writing

Why does this

```
Try{ Copy-Item -Path "D:\file.txt" -Destination "E:\file.txt"}
Catch { $_.Exception.Message|Add-Content C:\logs\copy.log}
```

give me an empty file? The log file exists. I have read&write permission to both file and D: drive. I've also tried with `Out-File -append` and `Out-File $_.Exception.Message, but I am not capturing any errors. The error is thrown in the console, telling me that

> Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\file.txt' because it does not exist. (...)

Comment: Add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Copy-Item` to make sure it goes into the `Catch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @kim: Adding `-ErrorAction Stop` did the trick!

```
Try{ Copy-Item -Path "D:\file.txt" -Destination "E:\file.txt" -ErrorAction Stop}
Catch { $_.Exception.Message|Add-Content C:\logs\copy.log}
```